# How to map a usb device with a known bus address to the mounted path?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, usb, libusb

I have an application which is using `libusb` for detecting connected usb devices. This library gives me the VID/PID and bus as well as port number of the connected devices. I however need (after recognizing the device by PID/VID) to talk to the device via `boost::asio::io_service`, for this i need the device path in the `/dev` directory. The device usually gets mounted as something like `/dev/ttyUSBx`. How do I match the bus and port number to the path? A cross platform solution which works on linux and macOS would be preferable. If there is no cross platform solution, are there ways for both OS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The not so straight forward but feasible way is to use sysfs like this:
Find the USB device you are looking for by browsing `/sys/class/tty/ttyUSBx`

`cd` into the directory of the device of your choice.

Execute `realpath .`

This will show you something like this: `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0`

`cd` to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0` and `cat uevent`.
This will contain the USB VID/PID under PRODUCT=xxxxxxxx

There is obviously some work required to automate it with C++ but it is doable.